# Movement caused by buoyancy

Tags: fluid, forces

I have a rod that can rotate about a point, the rotation is caused by the buoyancy of 3 balls connected to the rod as in the picture:

[image]

I need to calculate the angle at different heights and the submerged fraction of the second ball from the left for each angle.

I tried to calculate the submerged fraction of each ball individually using the angle (and thereby neglecting the gravitational forces).

But by doing the angle does not reduce when the water level falls since I only include the buoyancy forces. This is not right as the rod should follow the water level.

I don't know how to include the downwards forces for each ball.
This is a problem because (looking at the second ball from the left) the ball has the forces $F_{g2}$ and $F_{B2}$ acting on it but there will also be some force acting on this from the rest of the systems right?

So my question is how do I set up the forces acting on the middle ball?

I think the moment equation should be something like
$F_{g1} \cdot L_1 \cdot angle + F_{g2} \cdot L_2 \cdot angle + F_{g3} \cdot L_3 \cdot angle- F_{B1} \cdot L_1 \cdot angle - F_{B2} \cdot L_2 \cdot angle - F_{B3} \cdot L_3 \cdot angle$

thanks

Comment: Is the rod, a perfectly *rigid* rod ? Does the rod extend continuously from the ball-1 to the wall or are there actually 3 rods connected by 2 balls ?

Comment: The rod is rigid and extending continuosly

Comment: I think you missed some $\sin()$ in the equations. Equate your net moment to zero to indicate the equilibrium condition and then solve for $angle$. And the buoyancy forces are themselves functions of angle and water level; i.e. $F_{B1\ (angle,\ level)}$.

Comment: okay, what about if the system is constantly changing and I want to find the rotational velocity ?

Comment: Then, add an additional "*force*" term to the above and equate to zero. See [D Alembert's principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle). Or Newton's second law.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving the problem where the system is constantly changing, you are solving the differential equation (Newton's second law)

$$
I \frac{d^2\ \alpha}{dt^2} = \sum_i{(M_{gi} + M_{bi})}
= \sum_i{\left((F_{gi} + F_{bi\ (\alpha, level)})\cdot L_i \cdot \sin(\alpha)\right)}
$$

where $I$ is moment of inertia of the total system about the hinge point, $\alpha$ is the angle, $M_i$ are the torques, $F_i$ are the (gravitational and buoyancy) forces, $L_i$ are the distances to the balls from the hinge point.

Assumptions include (but not limited to)

- rigid mass less rod
- only forces acting are gravity and buoyancy